# Is there a function (object) template for pointer deletion available for re-use somewhere (boost, STL)?

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, containers

If I have a STL container that takes object pointers as elements, I will need to delete the pointers in the destructor of the class that has such a container. Since the operation of deleting a pointer

```
delete ptr_; 
ptr_ = 0;
```

might be often used, I wonder if there is a function (or function object) template that does this, defined in boost, or STL or by the standard somewhere as the function object DeletePointer defined in the following example:

```
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

template<class Pointer>
class DeletePointer
{
    public: 
        void operator()(Pointer t)
        {
            delete t; 
            t = 0;
        }
};

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    list<double*> doublePtrList;

    doublePtrList.push_back(new double (0));
    doublePtrList.push_back(new double (1));
    doublePtrList.push_back(new double (2));
    doublePtrList.push_back(new double (3));

    for_each(doublePtrList.begin(), doublePtrList.end(), DeletePointer<double*>());
};
```

Comment: Yes, it's called a smart pointer. A non-reference-counted one would basically do the same thing as `DeletePointer`, but without the need for the `for_each` call, and delete the pointer when the smart pointer goes out of scope.

Comment: Boost Pointer Container library might be what you need.

Comment: @jrok today `STD` support smart pointers. there is no need for the Boost library for that.

Comment: @chris Is there a smart pointer in STL that would *not* involve a transfer of ownership when I call a class method that returns this pointer by value?

Comment: @Roee ptr_x containers provide a level of abstraction over raw pointers so that you acces elements just like you would with containers with value semantics, e.g. pvec.begin().foo(). Might be relevant/useful for some people. Besides, not everyone can use c++11 just yet :shrug:

Comment: @tomislav-maric, `std::unique_ptr` would move the ownership from the one in the function to the one being returned. `std::shared_ptr` would cause both to have ownership.

Comment: @chris if it's unique_ptr AFAIK you can't return it normally as value. you must use "std::move" to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If (for some reason) you can't store smart pointers instead of raw pointers in your collection, consider using a Boost [pointer container](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html) instead.

Answer (score 1):

As others have suggested, it's a good idea to use a smart pointer instead of raw pointers whenever possible.

However, to directly answer your question, there is `std::default_delete` defined in `<memory>` (in C++11).

Comment: For C++ < C++11, you can use boost::checked_delete. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/utility/checked_delete.html

Answer (score 1):

just use shared pointers of std:

```
include <memory>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    list<shared_ptr<double>> doublePtrList;

    doublePtrList.push_back(make_shared<double>(0.0));
    doublePtrList.push_back(make_shared<double>(1.0));
    doublePtrList.push_back(make_shared<double>(2.0));
    doublePtrList.push_back(make_shared<double>(3.0));

    //for_each(doublePtrList.begin(), doublePtrList.end(), DeletePointer<double*>());

    //For clearing just clear the list
    doublePtrList.clear();
};
```

shared pointers automatically free delete the memory when no one reference it (or to be more correct when the last reference stop referencing it)

Comment: @JerryCoffin Also a pointer to double... but it's not my question. also I believe that in a lot of cases containers for shared pointer can make a lot of sense. depends of the situation.

Comment: What happens when a class that holds a list of shared pointers offers a member function that returns a shared pointer by value? Is the ownership of the object transfered then to the returned pointer?

Comment: @tomislav-maric when returning a shared pointer by value the reference count (RC) of the shared pointer increases to 2. if then the list is cleared the RC will decrease to 1 so the memory pointed remain. only when the pointer outside is freed the memory will be deleted.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Interested in your comment about containers of shared pointers rarely making much sense. Do you have any references you could share for this? I was looking at an admittedly [quite old article](http://www.drdobbs.com/collecting-shared-objects/184401839) by Herb Sutter that didn't imply any problem. I ask because I'm currently working with code which uses such an approach to keep multiply indexed views on a collection of objects. It has its own set of problems but I can't necessarily see a better way. (Client doesn't use Boost either so multi-index is out.)

Comment: @Component10: A multi-index type of setup sounds (at least to me) like one of the relatively rare cases where a container of shared_ptr could, perhaps, make sense. At least theoretically, you should have one collection that owns the data, and the other collections contain non-owning pointers though, so even here it's *somewhat* questionable.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Take the simple case of DB cache in multi-thread. I want the cache to load entity from the DB upon request and give them to the application. as long as the entity is valid the cache is providing a shared_point to the entity but when the entity is timed-out or the cache is flushed. I can delete the entry from the cache and reload it (if needed) for future requests without harming the data the application is already using at the moment and without the overhead of copying the data out for each request.